# What is a good proxy server for Linux that will allow me to connect through it?

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to set up a proxy server on Fedora Core 4.  Any idea of which ones might be easy to set up?  I would like to connect through that server and receive an IP address from my ISP, since I have IP-address filtering on my apache server.

Squid is an option, but I'm not sure how easy or hard it is to set up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you're familiar enough with apache it may be easier to set that up as a proxy ([mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)). squid is probably more robust though if you want a dedicated proxy.